# awk to print underscore

Tags: awk

I need `awk` to print underscore in the output. see below example

**Current Output**

```
  [root@looct ~]# date | awk '{print $2$3$6}'
   Nov142016
```

**Required Output**

```
Nov_14_2016   -----> I need this, is it possible?
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
date +%b_%d_%Y
```

will do it without an extra process.

Answer (score 3):

```
 date | awk '{print $2"_"$3"_"$6}'
```

or with `OFS`

```
date | awk -v OFS=_ '{print $2,$3,$6}'
```